Moving an object with two separate sources of influence
I am working on an fbx motion capture recording and I wanted to track a staff model (right) to the trackers (the four black empty axis on the left) so that it moves with the points and I wouldn't have to animate manually. But as far as I know I can't parent it because I can't have more than one parent for an object. Any ideas on how to make the staff track in sync with the empty axis points in the motion capture recording?
Edit: I have already tried child of constraints but the problem I'm running into is that the empty axis that track the motion capture data of the staff only move the staff model from its origin, so it remains in a weird parallel state for the entirety of the recording. Is there a way for the each axis to influence opposite ends of the staff so that it tracks the entire motion and not just affect the model's origin? Image is attached below with the two axis only connecting to the origin of the shape. The staff model only seems to float when I have two constraints active. but always connects to its origin.

